# Recurrence relation of Bell's polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

(I posted this yesterday, but after struggling and googling I noticed that this is a problem related to recurrence relation of Bell's polynomial. Hence, I reupload this with fine form using the term Bell's polymial)

Define $$Y_n(x_1,...,x_n):=\sum  \frac{n!}{(k_1)!...(k_n)!(1!)^{k_1}...(n!)^{k_n}} (x_1^{k_1}...x_{n}^{k_{n}})$$ where the summation is over $0\leq k_1,...,k_n\leq n$ such that $k_1+...+nk_{n}=n$.

This $Y_n$ is called the Bell's polynomial.

My question is the following:

How do I prove that $x_1Y_1(x_1,...,x_n)+\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i+1}\frac{\partial Y_n}{\partial x_i} (x_1,...,x_n)=Y_{n+1}(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$?

Is there any reference to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write that thing just as $Y_n$, to avoid clutter. If I'm not
mistaken, then we have
$$\Phi(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Y_n\frac{t^n}{n!}
=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\frac{t^k}{k!}\right).\tag{1}$$
Let $\mathscr D$ be the differential operator
$$\mathscr D =x_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_{k+1}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_k}.
$$
Applying this to the right side of $(1)$ gives
$$\mathscr D\Phi(t)=
\left(x_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_{k+1}\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)\Phi(t)
=\Phi'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Y_{n+1}\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$
Now compare coefficients of $t^n$.

Comment: Where can I see the proof for that generating form $(1)$ and related badic stuffs on Bell polynomial? Is there any text? Thank you

Comment: @Rubertos I just made that up, I don't know a reference. To prove (1) just write the RHS as $\prod_{k=1}^n\exp(x_kt^k/k!)$ and just expand.